# After rounding, how do I render negative zeroes like positive zeroes?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

When I format these two values:

```
0.0001
-0.0001
```

like this formula in Custom formatting:

```
_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);
```

I see:

```
$  (0.00)
$   0.00
```

I can make them look the same with an `IF` statement and adding a small number to the near-zero negative values. Is there an easier way to make them look the same while keeping the usual behavior for positive and negative numbers?

Comment: Why not just use conditional formatting?

Comment: @DavidZemens , if you would extend it a bit your comment would serve well as an answer

Comment: Currently writing an answer @K_B :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use conditional formatting.

You can use this in conjunction with the custom format you have already assigned.  In the Custom Formatting UI, do this:

[image: Conditional Formatting Rule]

Then set the Number conditional formatting like this `_($* #,##0.00_);_($* #,##0.00_);` which will treat positive & negative values the same ONLY when the rounded value = 0.

[image: Custom Font Format Rule - Conditional Formatting]

**Further information:**

Formatting applies to the *values*, not to what the values *look like* after the formatting has been applied.

[From Microsoft](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-a-custom-number-format-HP010342372.aspx), with Custom Formatting you can specify formats for Positive, Negative, Zero, and Text values. There is no option to formulaicly derive whether a value should be treated like another type of value, without using a conditional formatting rule(s).

> A number format can have up to four sections of code, separated by
>   semicolons. These code sections define the format for positive
>   numbers, negative numbers, zero values, and text, in that order.
>
> `<POSITIVE>;<NEGATIVE>;<ZERO>;<TEXT>`